# Does the .babelrc preset choice ["es2015", "stage-0"] skip es2016 and point to the current stage 0 proposals?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am following a .babelrc code sample from a JavaScript book by Manning called "Get Programming with Javascript Next" that was published in 2018 (and presumably written in 2016-2017). The book explains the stages of TC39 proposals then recommends this setup for working on the code samples.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
  "sourceMaps": "inline"
}
```

Note: I see that these presets are deprecated right now and I read the reasons why. However being new to modern JavaScript I am not sure what to replace them with.

Does using the ["es2015", "stage-0"] .babelrc preset choice right now in April 2019 skip es2016 and point to the current stage 0 proposals? If so what would be a good setup for working with es2015, es2016 and proposals that **would have been** stage 0 proposals 2 years ago?